# Are no orphaned blocks mined in the Bitcoin network?

Tags: blockchain-fork, stale-block

I can't find orphaned blocks in the Bitcoin network from July with references to blockchain.info. 
Does this mean the bitcoin network centralization? 
I like C. Decker's paper "Information Propagation in the Bitcion Network." 
But if the stale rate is 0, this paper's equation can't apply to the Bitcoin.

Comment: This is the chart of orphand blocks. 
https://blockchain.info/ja/charts/n-orphaned-blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably the chart at https://blockchain.info/ja/charts/n-orphaned-blocks is broken. here you can see some new orphans blocks: https://blockchain.info/en/orphaned-blocks

Comment: Thank you very much!
My question is cleared. I can sleep well tonight  : )

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this link,m it looks more relevant 
https://www.blockchain.com/en/btc/orphaned-blocks